# SlidingMenu and ViewPager cause Recursive Entry

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using the `SlidingMenu` to create a Google+ like interface. Because of `SlidingMenu` I have one Activity and multiple Fragments, one for each item of the menu.

The main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/above_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The above_layout is added a fragment on onCreate:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.above_layout, new MyFrag1()).commit();
```

The MyFrag1 has a `ViewPager` with an `FragmentPagerAdapter` to display multiple lists.

At this point all works perfect and really fast. 
After I added the code to replace the fragment with another one:

```
        Fragment frag = MyFrag2.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.above_layout, frag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

The new fragment loads perfectly but after I click the Back button it crashes with:

```
Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample, maybe it could help you :-)
https://github.com/Alexrs95/SlidingMenuAndViewPager